# Executing query (multiple/ subquery) in HIVE is giving Vertex Failed

Tags: sql, hive

I have a basic understanding of HIVE and SQL Query. So the query that i have has multiple individual query or you can say sub query. However, if i run 5-6 query together it is working fine but if i run the whole query (99 individual query) it is giving me Vertex Failed Error

Query:

```
Select "TABLE_NAME_2" as TBL_NAME,  (Select count(*)  from a_t2 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  a,    (Select count(*)  from b_t2 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  b,    (Select count(*)  from c_t2 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  c     UNION ALL
Select "TABLE_NAME_3" as TBL_NAME,  (Select count(*)  from a_t3 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  a,    (Select count(*)  from b_t3 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  b,    (Select count(*)  from c_t3 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  c     UNION ALL
Select "TABLE_NAME_4" as TBL_NAME,  (Select count(*)  from a_t4 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  a,    (Select count(*)  from b_t4 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  b,    (Select count(*)  from c_t4 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  c     UNION ALL
Select "TABLE_NAME_5" as TBL_NAME,  (Select count(*)  from a_t5 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  a,    (Select count(*)  from b_t5 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  b,    (Select count(*)  from c_t5 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  c     UNION ALL
Select "TABLE_NAME_6" as TBL_NAME,  (Select count(*)  from a_t6 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  a,    (Select count(*)  from b_t6 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  b,    (Select count(*)  from c_t6 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  c     UNION ALL
.
.
.
.
.
Select "TABLE_NAME_33" as TBL_NAME, (Select count(*)  from a_t33 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  a,   (Select count(*)  from b_t33 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  b,   (Select count(*)  from c_t33 where BDATE='2023-05-31') as  c
```

Not sure if this is the limitation of HIVE DB or if i am missing something.

Note: I have also used

```
set tez.queue.name = APPNAME; 
set hive.execution.engine = tez;
```

**EDITED**
Output i want is:

```
TBL_NAME     a    b   c
TABLE_NAME1  10   20  15
TABLE_NAME2  10   20  15
TABLE_NAME3  10   20  15
.
.
.
TABLE_NAME33  10   20  15
```

Thanks

Comment: The syntax is all wrong you union table or join them, you could remove all selects except the first that would also yield a valid query, another valid query would be to put parenthesis around all selects , but only scalar values are allowed but without details it is hard to grasp what you want

Comment: Hi @nbk, if possible can you give me one example that would be really appreciated and helpful.. I have a very basic understanding of Query writing. So all the technical words are really tough for me to understand as of now.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=27362049#content/view/27362049. But your don't know how many tables are supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can give you some solution. Like @nbk said syntax is wrong and this kind of inline SQL doesnt wotk in hive. But this is going to be an expensive solution - seek for some partitions in this table and see if you can count partitioned rows.

Here is something you can try -

```
WITH 
TABLE_NAME_2_a as Select "TABLE_NAME_2" as TBL_NAME,  SUM(case when BDATE='2023-05-31' then 1 else 0 end) as  a from a_t2 ,
TABLE_NAME_2_b as Select "TABLE_NAME_2" as TBL_NAME,  SUM(case when BDATE='2023-05-31' then 1 else 0 end) as  a from b_t2 ,
TABLE_NAME_2_c as Select "TABLE_NAME_2" as TBL_NAME,  SUM(case when BDATE='2023-05-31' then 1 else 0 end) as  a from c_t2 ,
TABLE_NAME_3_a as Select "TABLE_NAME_3" as TBL_NAME,  SUM(case when BDATE='2023-05-31' then 1 else 0 end) as  a from a_t3 ,
TABLE_NAME_3_b as Select "TABLE_NAME_3" as TBL_NAME,  SUM(case when BDATE='2023-05-31' then 1 else 0 end) as  a from b_t3 ,
TABLE_NAME_3_c as Select "TABLE_NAME_3" as TBL_NAME,  SUM(case when BDATE='2023-05-31' then 1 else 0 end) as  a from c_t3 

--UNION for Table 2
select 
TABLE_NAME_2_a.TBL_NAME, TABLE_NAME_2_a.a, TABLE_NAME_2_b.b,TABLE_NAME_2_c.c
from 
TABLE_NAME_2_a,TABLE_NAME_2_b,TABLE_NAME_2_c 
where 
TABLE_NAME_2_a.TBL_NAME=TABLE_NAME_2_b.TBL_NAME and TABLE_NAME_2_a.TBL_NAME=TABLE_NAME_2_c.TBL_NAME 
union all 
--UNION for Table 3
select 
TABLE_NAME_3_a.TBL_NAME, TABLE_NAME_3_a.a, TABLE_NAME_3_b.b,TABLE_NAME_3_c.c
from       
TABLE_NAME_3_a,TABLE_NAME_3_b,TABLE_NAME_3_c 
where      
TABLE_NAME_3_a.TBL_NAME=TABLE_NAME_3_b.TBL_NAME and TABLE_NAME_3_a.TBL_NAME=TABLE_NAME_3_c.TBL_NAME
```